# javascript return random data which contains a specific array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to generate a random object which contains a specific id. For example I want to return objects which contains id 3, the first and third one in the example below:

```
results = [

{title: "A", ids: [2,3,4,]},

{title: "B", ids: [9,4,7]},

{title: "C", ids: [1,3,4]}

]

let data = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)]

return data
```

This is what I tried:

```
 data.map(function (genre){
   let random = genre === 3;
   return random;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to `filter` the `results` based on the value of `data`

```
results.filter(function(x) { return x.ids.includes(data) })
```